# Direct install with new SSD single OS

Tags: ssd

I have an ASUS Eee PC netbook. I have 2gb ram(new) and a new SSD.  I do not have any OS loaded.  I need to know how to install ubuntu on it from a flash drive.  I have the 32bit version on my flash drive already but I keep getting "begin loading essential drivers" repeating during the install process.   Can someone show me the way to install?

Comment: You need an installable copy of Ubuntu, but no specific requirements (or special instructions) to install current (eg. **14.04 LTS**) Ubuntu version with an SSD drive. *How did you create your flash drive?*

Comment: I created the drive using Linux live USB creator to make the flash drive.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you do this under? .. for what version to install?

Comment: We tried 14.4, 12.4, jolicloud, and zorin.  all with no luck.  Any Sugguestions?  this is the pc:  http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1005HA_Seashell/          but with a Kingston V300 120 GB SATA HD and Crucial 2GB PC2-6400 RAM stick, which I installed myself.

Comment: I've loaded **12.04** and **14.04** onto the HP Mini 210 series (essentially the same as Eee-PC) too many times, with no issues. *You may need to check the **ISO** file (or re-download), or try creating USB 'LiveCD' on different PC.*